# Huge performance loss with small query in Postgres (but not SQLServ)

Tags: sql-server, performance, postgresql, join, query-performance

With Postgres 9.4, I'm having a disturbing performance loss with very simple queries. This is real handicap and is blocking my migration.

*Note: this problem doesn't exist this in my SQL Server 2014 DWH.*

The idea is easy: to count the element of dim_activity, grouping by product_key and country_key. Yet, I want to retrieve the product_string and country_string instead of product_key and country_key. Therefore, I join.

- dim_activity has 10M rows
- dim_country has 20 rows
- dim_box has less than 1k rows
- Joins are not increasing the number of rows.
- The tables are on different schemas but same tablespace

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT
    c.country_code,    
    b.real_box_sku,
    COUNT(*)
FROM "DWH_activity".dim_activity a
LEFT JOIN "DWH_main".dim_box b ON a.box_key=b.box_key
LEFT JOIN "DWH_main".dim_country c ON a.country_key=c.country_key
WHERE a.event_type IN('New Customer','Reactivation','Active','Simple')
GROUP BY
    c.country_code,
    b.real_box_sku
```

This takes more than ***4mins+***, here is the query plan:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=1648008.80..1724929.95 rows=52200 width=25) (actual time=223523.127..271740.258 rows=425 loops=1)"
"  Output: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku, count(*)"
"  Group Key: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku"
"  Buffers: shared hit=2 read=77611, temp read=51224 written=51224"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1648008.80..1667108.59 rows=7639915 width=25) (actual time=223518.029..269632.659 rows=7628149 loops=1)"
"        Output: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku"
"        Sort Key: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 186416kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=77611, temp read=51224 written=51224"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=59.51..408988.74 rows=7639915 width=25) (actual time=0.688..9803.950 rows=7628149 loops=1)"
"              Output: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku"
"              Hash Cond: (a.country_key = c.country_key)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=77611"
"              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=35.79..303916.18 rows=7639915 width=15) (actual time=0.661..7129.092 rows=7628149 loops=1)"
"                    Output: a.country_key, b.real_box_sku"
"                    Hash Cond: (a.box_key = b.box_key)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=77610"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_activity".dim_activity a  (cost=0.00..198831.57 rows=7639915 width=6) (actual time=0.020..4032.800 rows=7628149 loops=1)"
"                          Output: a.country_key, a.vertical, a.cust_key, a.sub_key, a.fact_key, a.event_date_at, a.event_time_at, a.box_key, a.sub_type, a.activity_before, a.event_type, a.reason_key"
"                          Filter: ((a.event_type)::text = ANY ('{"New Customer",Reactivation,Active,Simple}'::text[]))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 454422"
"                          Buffers: shared read=77593"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=26.46..26.46 rows=746 width=17) (actual time=0.631..0.631 rows=746 loops=1)"
"                          Output: b.real_box_sku, b.box_key"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 37kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=17"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_main".dim_box b  (cost=0.00..26.46 rows=746 width=17) (actual time=0.011..0.359 rows=746 loops=1)"
"                                Output: b.real_box_sku, b.box_key"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=2 read=17"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=16.10..16.10 rows=610 width=16) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                    Output: c.country_code, c.country_key"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"                    Buffers: shared read=1"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_main".dim_country c  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=610 width=16) (actual time=0.009..0.013 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                          Output: c.country_code, c.country_key"
"                          Buffers: shared read=1"
"Planning time: 0.447 ms"
"Execution time: 271781.990 ms"
```

**QUERY2** : SAME but only one JOIN (exact same perf on each of the joined tables)

```
 SELECT
    c.country_code,
    COUNT(*)
FROM "DWH_activity".dim_activity a
LEFT JOIN "DWH_main".dim_country c ON a.country_key=c.country_key
GROUP BY
    c.country_code
```

This takes **5sec**, here is the query plan:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=309990.64..309992.64 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=5943.200..5943.200 rows=7 loops=1)"
"  Output: c.country_code, count(*)"
"  Group Key: c.country_code"
"  Buffers: shared read=77594"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=23.73..269577.79 rows=8082571 width=12) (actual time=0.037..3873.109 rows=8082571 loops=1)"
"        Output: c.country_code"
"        Hash Cond: (a.country_key = c.country_key)"
"        Buffers: shared read=77594"
"        ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_activity".dim_activity a  (cost=0.00..158418.71 rows=8082571 width=2) (actual time=0.016..1261.439 rows=8082571 loops=1)"
"              Output: a.country_key, a.vertical, a.cust_key, a.sub_key, a.fact_key, a.event_date_at, a.event_time_at, a.box_key, a.sub_type, a.activity_before, a.event_type, a.reason_key"
"              Buffers: shared read=77593"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=16.10..16.10 rows=610 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=14 loops=1)"
"              Output: c.country_code, c.country_key"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"              Buffers: shared read=1"
"              ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_main".dim_country c  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=610 width=16) (actual time=0.006..0.011 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                    Output: c.country_code, c.country_key"
"                    Buffers: shared read=1"
"Planning time: 0.140 ms"
"Execution time: 5943.249 ms"
```

**QUERY3**: I make a first count then join then aggregate

```
SELECT
    c.country_code,    
    b.real_box_sku,
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT
    country_key,
    box_key,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM "DWH_activity".dim_activity a
    GROUP BY
    country_key,
    box_key
) a
LEFT JOIN "DWH_main".dim_box b ON a.box_key=b.box_key
LEFT JOIN "DWH_main".dim_country c ON a.country_key=c.country_key
GROUP BY
    c.country_code,
    b.real_box_sku
```

this takes ***3sec***, here is the query plan:

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=219263.82..219294.06 rows=3024 width=25) (actual time=3990.415..3990.492 rows=425 loops=1)"
"  Output: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku, count(*)"
"  Group Key: c.country_code, b.real_box_sku"
"  Buffers: shared hit=35 read=77578"
"  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=219097.50..219241.14 rows=3024 width=25) (actual time=3989.832..3990.232 rows=440 loops=1)"
"        Output: b.real_box_sku, c.country_code"
"        Hash Cond: (a.country_key = c.country_key)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=35 read=77578"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=219073.78..219175.84 rows=3024 width=15) (actual time=3989.815..3990.073 rows=440 loops=1)"
"              Output: a.country_key, b.real_box_sku"
"              Hash Cond: (a.box_key = b.box_key)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=34 read=77578"
"              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=219037.99..219068.23 rows=3024 width=6) (actual time=3989.414..3989.508 rows=440 loops=1)"
"                    Output: a.country_key, a.box_key, count(*)"
"                    Group Key: a.country_key, a.box_key"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=32 read=77561"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_activity".dim_activity a  (cost=0.00..158418.71 rows=8082571 width=6) (actual time=0.024..1115.551 rows=8082571 loops=1)"
"                          Output: a.country_key, a.vertical, a.cust_key, a.sub_key, a.fact_key, a.event_date_at, a.event_time_at, a.box_key, a.sub_type, a.activity_before, a.event_type, a.reason_key"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=32 read=77561"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=26.46..26.46 rows=746 width=17) (actual time=0.378..0.378 rows=746 loops=1)"
"                    Output: b.real_box_sku, b.box_key"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 37kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=17"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_main".dim_box b  (cost=0.00..26.46 rows=746 width=17) (actual time=0.011..0.210 rows=746 loops=1)"
"                          Output: b.real_box_sku, b.box_key"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=2 read=17"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=16.10..16.10 rows=610 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=14 loops=1)"
"              Output: c.country_code, c.country_key"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1"
"              ->  Seq Scan on "DWH_main".dim_country c  (cost=0.00..16.10 rows=610 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=14 loops=1)"
"                    Output: c.country_code, c.country_key"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1"
"Planning time: 0.220 ms"
"Execution time: 3990.589 ms"
```

So, it looks like aggregating with more than one join makes my query not runnable

Because of this, most of our reports would have to be depreciated or could be impossible to run...

Thanks for the help ;)

**EDIT1:** I have replace the query plain analyze by the output of explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, following a_horse_with_no_name's request

Comment: Please add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` not just plain `analyze`

Comment: 1) lack of FK constraints (+supporting indexes) 2) lack of valid statistics.

Comment: Could this be the reason of the problem:

Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 186416kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=77611, temp read=51224 written=51224" ?

It looks it's wirting on the disk, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it could! Add proper FKs, also add an index on dim_activity.event_type

Comment: Vincent: no, it is not the *reason* of the problem, it is a *result* of the problem. Adding the correct structure to your data model will (probably) cause the optimiser to generate a better plan.

Comment: @joop : thanks, I'll create the FK constraints and supporting indexes.

Yet, I ddin't have any in the MSSQL either..

Comment: Thanks both, i'll do this tonight and post the result tomorrow :)
@Joop: what do you mean by "lack of valid statistics" ?

Comment: Statistics are maintained *dynamically* by PG. After (initial) loading of the data there are no (adequate) statistics. Statistics will be updated over time, or once the table is updated. Also: statistics are only maintained for columns that are (part of) keys.

Comment: Quick update: I first investigated the "Buffers: shared hit=2 read=77611, temp read=51224 written=51224" problem; used pg_tune and improve config => the aforementioned problem disappeared in most of the case.

I'll now take care of the FK constraint issue in order to fix it once and for all. Will post final feedback when done. Thanks